# call one function into another in js without HTML file

Tags: javascript, node.js

This was interview question for me. How we can access a function defined in one.js in two.js?

I told them an answer using HTML, but they were looking for an answer that didn't involve linking via the HTML.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you can control the script tag of `one.js`, make it a module, and `import` from `two.js`:

```
<script type="module" src="one.js">
```

```
// one.js
import { foo } from './two.js';
foo();
```

```
// two.js
export const foo = () => {
  console.log('foo running');
};
```

ES6 modules in the browser aren't supported *everywhere*, but they're supported on most modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

They might have been asking for [Node.js `require`](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/).

Here is an example of what that might look like, calling a function from `one.js` in `two.js`:

```js
// one.js
module.exports = function () {
    console.log('Hello World')
}
```

```js
// two.js
const myFunction = require('./two.js')
myFunction()
```